# Пустой photos_list при работе с VK API

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Загружаю фотографию к себе в альбом согласно [документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=1.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC):

*процедуры авторизации, получения id альбома, адреса для загрузки опущены, т.к. работают корректно*

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file1', file.files[0]);
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", upload_url, true );
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(data)
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  xhr.send(formData);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<button id="button">OK</button>
```

Однако в ответе от сервера приходит пустое свойство `photos_list:"[]"` что делает невозможным дальнейшее сохранение фотографии.
Долгое и упорное гугление не привело меня ни к чему, кроме информации о том, что пустое свойство photos_list указывает на то, что я не передаю никаких файлов серверу.

Однако (на мой взгляд) я действую согласно документации.
Ниже привожу headers самого POST запроса:

```
Request URL:https://pu.vk.com/c636925/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=12591728&aid=221386829&gid=0&hash=092d7aa4авыgad01d984ebaca84cf6159dcfb85&rhash=b2771b5f5g6b6f40asd304e239e46574076cb3&swfupload=1&api=1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:87.240.165.92:443
Response Headers
cache-control:no-store
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:105
content-type:text/html; charset=windows-1251
date:Tue, 21 Mar 2017 10:17:09 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:nginx
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by:PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2
Request Headers
:authority:pu.vk.com
:method:POST
:path:/c636925/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=1259321728&aid=2216386829&gid=0&hash=092d7a4asdgf01984ebaca84cf6159dsdcfb85&rhash=b2771b5fasd56b6f4d0304e9e46574076cb3&swfupload=1&api=1
:scheme:https
accept:*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
content-length:4469
content-type:multipart/form-data
origin:http://evil.com/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
x-compress:null
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
act:do_add
mid:12591728
aid:221386829
gid:0
hash:0s92d7aasd4a0hh1984esgfbaca84asdcf6159dacfb85
rhash:b2771bgh5f556fghb6f403304e9h4fe346574076cb3
swfupload:1
api:1
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarynspHTlbJ4EXApLsK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="128x128.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarynspHTlbJ4EXApLsK--
```

Comment: Сверяйте то что отсылается с тем как прописано в документации (и нам приведите свой запрос)

Comment: В документации написано:
Поле POST-запроса: file{i}, i=[1..5]. 

Я это понимаю как 

`formData.append('file1', file.files[0]);
formData.append('file2', file.files[1]);
formData.append('file3', file.files[2]);
formData.append('file4', file.files[3]);
formData.append('file5', file.files[4]);`
`
В самом запросе в Request Payload содержится:

------WebKitFormBoundarynspHTlbJ4EXApLsK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="128x128.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarynspHTlbJ4EXApLsK--

Comment: Не очень понял под "что отсылается" - вы имеете ввиду файл?
"как прописано в документации" - прописано слать formData с полем file1.

привести запрос, вы хотите взглянуть на headers самого POST запроса?